# use of undeclared identifier soundfileURLRef

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have this code in place for sound for my app, but I do not know what to do with all of these errors.

The Code for the ViewController.h IS (no errors appear, but just in case you need the info):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface pstViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)playsound;


@end
```

The Code for the ViewController.m IS (3 errors):

```
#import "pstViewController.h"

@interface pstViewController ()

@end

@implementation pstViewController




-(IBAction)playsound;
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundfile;
    soundfileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Spaz Music"CFSTR             (    ("band"), NULL)
    UInt32 SoundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundfileURLRef, &SoundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (SoundID);
```

Errors appear as follows:

1) ON THIS LINE THE ERROR STATES THAT THERE IS A USE OF AN UNDECLARED IDENTIFIER soundfileURLRef:

soundfileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Spaz Music", CFSTR ("band"), NULL)

2) SAME EXACT ERROR AS #1 ON THIS LINE:

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundfileURLRef, &SoundID);

3) THIS HAS A USE OF A UNDECLARED IDENTIFIER SoundID

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (SoundID);

Comment: What is the name of your sound file and the extension ?

Answer (score 0):

**Play short sound clip,**

```
 SystemSoundID soundID;

 if(soundID == 0){

    //play the myaudio.caff file in the main bundle 
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myaudio" ofType:@"caff"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundId((CFURLRef) url, &soundID);
 }

 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```